# A projective module over a finite direct product of fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra, projective-module

Is a projective  module $P$ over a ring $R$ which is a finite  direct product of fields free?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Did you try $\mathbb Z/2$ and $\mathbb Z/2\oplus\mathbb Z/2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For example, $K\times\{0\}$ is a projective module over the ring $K\times L$ (being a direct summand of the free module $K\times L\cong (K\times \{0\})\oplus (\{0\}\times L)$). But it is not free.

More generally, over $K\times L$, any module of the form $K^n\times L^m$, with $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$, is projective. Such a module is free if and only if $n=m$.